# Can I install ubuntu over Vista on a laptop computer?

Tags: windows-vista

Can I install ubuntu OS over the Vista OS on a Compaq laptop.  Are there any instructions out there for this???

Comment: Hello @user172105, Welcome to AskUbuntu. Well, yours seems to be a common question, and it has been answered in the past. Even when it refers to a "beside a Windows XP installation" the process is exactly the same. Check this answer in order to get a step-by-step procedure. http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/9598 Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WUBI installer: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

This gives you the impression that you are installing Ubuntu 'over' your existing OS. In reality, it's just a nifty tool that does replaces the legwork need to go the old fashioned route of having a 'dual-boot' setup in which you have a separate disk partition (or physical disk) for each OS you want. There is a selection screen (called a bootloader) after the BIOS at which point you can select which OS you'd like to boot.

The only way to truly have one OS 'over' another OS is to use virtualization of some sort. There are many options here. If you want to go that route, it would be best to do some research and come back here with questions :)